# Show that a linear multistep method is of rank $p$ $\Leftrightarrow$ its local trunctation error is equal to 0 for any $x \in \pi_p$

Tags: numerical-methods, truncation-error

We have the following ODE: $$x'(t) = f(t,x) \quad \wedge \quad  x(t_0) = x_0$$

Let's say we have a linear multistep ($q$ steps) method:

$$\sum_{j=0}^q \alpha_j x_{k+j} = h \sum_{j=0}^q \beta_j f_{k+j}$$

It's local truncation error is equal to:

$$\sum_{j=0}^q (\alpha_j x(t_k + h j) -h \beta_j x' (t_k + hj))$$

If we assume that $x \in \pi_3$, this means, that:

$$x(t) = {\gamma}_0 + {\gamma}_1 t + ... + {\gamma}_p t^p$$

$$x'(t) = {\gamma}_1 + 2{\gamma}_2 t + ... + p {\gamma}_p t^{p-1}$$

This means, that:

$$\alpha_j x(t_k + h j) = \alpha_j{\gamma}_0 + \alpha_j{\gamma}_1 (t_k + h j) + ... + \alpha_j{\gamma}_p (t_k + h j)^p$$

$$-h \beta_j x'(t_k + h j) = -h \beta_j{\gamma}_1 - 2h \beta_j{\gamma}_2 (t_k + h j) - ... - p h \beta_j{\gamma}_p (t_k + h j)^{p-1}$$

Now let's add these two together, and we get:

$$\sum_{j=0}^q ((\alpha_j {\gamma}_0 - h \beta_j {\gamma}_1) + (\alpha_j {\gamma}_1 - 2h \beta_j {\gamma}_2)(t_k + hj) + ... + (\alpha_j {\gamma}_{p-1} - p h \beta_j {\gamma}_p)(t_k + hj)^{p-1} + (\alpha_j {\gamma}_p) (t_k + hj)^p)$$

This must be equal to zero. This means, that:

$$\sum_{j=0}^q ({\gamma}_p \alpha_j) = 0$$

$$\sum_{j=0}^q ({\gamma}_{p-1} \alpha_j - p h \beta_j {\gamma}_p) = 0$$

$$...$$

$$\sum_{j=0}^q ({\gamma}_0 \alpha_j - h \beta_j {\gamma}_1) = 0$$

Because $\sum_{j=0}^q ({\gamma}_{p-1} \alpha_j - p h \beta_j {\gamma}_p) = 0$, ..., $\sum_{j=0}^q ({\gamma}_0 \alpha_j - h \beta_j {\gamma}_1) = 0$, we can write this shorter as:

$$\sum_{j=0}^q ({\gamma}_p \alpha_j) = 0$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^p \sum_{j=0}^q ({\gamma}_{k-1} \alpha_j - h \beta_j {\gamma}_k) = 0$$

---

Now it get's to the point where my attempt to prove this theorem fails:

There is a theorem, that if we have a linear multistep (of $q$ steps) method, then it is of rank $p$, if:

$$c_0 = \sum_{j=0}^q \alpha_j = 0$$

And for all $k = 1, ..., p$:

$$c_k = \sum_{j=0}^q (\frac{1}{k!} j^k \alpha_j - \frac{1}{(k-1)!} j^{k-1} \beta_j) = 0$$

And $c_{p+1} \neq 0$

Again, instead of $\forall$ we can write it shorter:

$$\sum_{j=0}^q \alpha_j = 0$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^p \sum_{j=0}^q (\frac{1}{k!} j^k \alpha_j - \frac{1}{(k-1)!} j^{k-1} \beta_j) = 0$$

Now let's compare it to what we got previously:

$$\sum_{j=0}^q ({\gamma}_p \alpha_j) = 0$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^p \sum_{j=0}^q ({\gamma}_{k-1} \alpha_j - h \beta_j {\gamma}_k) = 0$$

It's pretty easy to see, that if $\sum_{j=0}^q \alpha_j = 0$, then $\sum_{j=0}^q ({\gamma}_p \alpha_j) = 0$ and vice versa (we either multiply oth sides by $\gamma_p$, or divide both sides).

But what about $\sum_{k=1}^p \sum_{j=0}^q ({\gamma}_{k-1} \alpha_j - h \beta_j {\gamma}_k) = 0$? That's where I am stuck

Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: When comparing coefficients, you compare for powers in $h$. There is no $h$ in the resulting coefficient relations. The method coefficients in general are independent of the step size $h$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I see. But this would be a lot of writing out, can I somehow do this in a shorter way?

Comment: You can compute this for each power separately, that is, for the general power function $p(t)=t^m$. You can shift the basis time to $t_k=0$.